# seminorms and product topology

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm studying Conway's functional analysis by myself. So some questions which may be simple is not clear for me. My question is the following:

If $\{X_i: I\in I\}$ is a family of TVS, then $X =\sqcap\{X_i: I\in I\} $ with the product topology is a TVS. If each $X_i$ is a LCS, show that so is $X$. If $X$ is a LCS, must each $X_i$ be a LCS?

Please help me. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

For the first part, to show that $(X,\tau,+,*)$ is a topological vector space, you only need to show that $+$ and $*$ are continuous with respect to the topology $\tau$. You know that they are "componentwise continuous", because the $X_i$ are topological vector spaces. You should be able to show that if $\prod_{i \in I} X_i$ is endowed with the product topology, $f(x) = \{ f_i(x) : i \in I \}$, and each $f_i$ is continuous, then $f$ is continuous. Hint: note that products of open sets are a base for the product topology.